# Signing Zip Files with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Firstly, I write something to convert folders to zip files
Now I want to sign these files. 
How can i do that with VBscript?

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/crypt_create_p7m_using_pfx.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you would use some third party ActiveX, most of the time not for free. You can however circumvent this by using a Zipfile manager from the command-line. 7-zip for example has a command-line interface that is included in the standard version. First try this out interactive until you have the correct syntax, then run this command with

```
ShowWindow = false
WaitUntilFinished = true
nRetCode = WshShell.Run "cmd /c <path to 7zip>\7z.exe <parameters>", DontShowWindow, WaitUntilFinished
```